# How to create Weekend Seasonality in Prophet?

Tags: python, time-series, prophet

I want to add custom seasonality in Prophet for weekend only (only count Saturday and Sunday). There is a `period` parameter. What value should I set?

As I know, if you want to create weekly seasonality you can set `period` to 7, and if you want to create monthly seasonality you can set `period` to 30.5. If the case is for weekend only, what value should I set?

Is it true if you set it like this? I have created one columns called "is_weekend" to identify if the date is in Saturday or Sunday. But I'm not sure this is the right way to do.

```
m.add_seasonality(name="weekend_seasonality",period=2,fourier_order=3,condition_name="is_weekend")
```